# How do i reduce response time

Tags: performance, web, roundtrip

I am loading a jsp, in which there is an internal request to another server.

eg.

```
<html>
      <head>
       </head>
      <body>
            <div> Welcome to....</div>
            .....
            .....

      <%
            HttpConnection conn = new HttpConnection("http://someothersite/somepage");
            conn.getResponse ();
      %>

            <div><%=response%></div>
      ....
      </html>
```

what are all the better ways to reduce the response time in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Asynchronous Javascript(AJAX).
The response time may be the same. But it will not block the other parts of your page to get loaded. Populate the required div with the Ajax response.
You may get a lot of articles regarding how to use AJAX on a google search.

Answer (score -3):

> > > > Less database connection and use optimize query.
> > > >         use to cache js and picture